# MemoryError in Python: How can I optimise my code?

Tags: python, memory, iteration

I have a number of json files to combine and output as a single csv (to load into R), with each json file at about 1.5gb.  While doing a trial on 4-5 json files at 250mb each, I get the following error below.  I'm running Python version `'2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'` on 8gb ram and Windows 7 professional 64 bit.

I'm a Python novice and have little experience with writing optimized code and would appreciate guidance on how I can optimize my script below.  Thank you!

======= Python MemoryError =======

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\tweetjson_to_csv.py", line 52, in <module>
    for line in file:
MemoryError
[Finished in 29.5s]
```

======= json to csv conversion script =======

```
# csv file that you want to save to
out = open("output.csv", "ab")

filenames = ["8may.json", "9may.json", "10may.json", "11may.json", "12may.json"]
open_files = map(open, filenames)

# change argument to the file you want to open
for file in open_files:
    for line in file:
        # only keep tweets and not the empty lines
        if line.rstrip():
            try:
                tweets.append(json.loads(line))
            except:
                pass

for tweet in tweets:
    ids.append(tweet["id_str"])
    texts.append(tweet["text"])
    time_created.append(tweet["created_at"])
    retweet_counts.append(tweet["retweet_count"])
... ...

print >> out, "ids,text,time_created,retweet_counts,in_reply_to,geos,coordinates,places,country,language,screen_name,followers,friends,statuses,locations"
rows = zip(ids,texts,time_created,retweet_counts,in_reply_to_screen_name,geos,coordinates,places,places_country,lang,user_screen_names,user_followers_count,user_friends_count,user_statuses_count,user_locations)

csv = writer(out)

for row in rows:
    values = [(value.encode('utf8') if hasattr(value, 'encode') else value) for value in row]
    csv.writerow(values)

out.close()
```

Comment: You're loading everything into memory (`tweets.append(json.loads(line))`). Can you phrase your algorithm in a way such that you write to `output.csv` immediately after reading each line?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: But, while I'm here, you should just open the files one at a time. No reason to open them all at once. Especially since you're not closing them when you're done with them.

Comment: thanks @dano.  How should I amend the code so I close files when I'm done with them?

Comment: Use `with` statements: `with open("some.file") as f: ...`.

Comment: I would recommend having the outer loop be `for filename in filenames:`, then a `with open(filename) as f:` block inside that, and then your inner `for line in f:` loop nested inside that. If you do it this way, the file will automatically close when you leave the `with ...` scope.

Comment: You could try writing a class made of functions, instead of just slapping everything together with for loops.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis How will classes help? This seems like straight forward  imperative programming requirement. Open file, read line, close file. Not every problem needs to be solved with OOP.

Comment: Opening and closing CSV files is fine... but that's not all that's going on here.

Comment: No this thats pretty much all thats going on here. Open CSV file, make arrays, munge arrays, write CSV file. Absolutely no need for classes here at all.

Answer (score 3):

This line right here:

```
open_files = map(open, filenames)
```

Opens every file at once concurrently.

Then you read everything and munge it into the same single array `tweets`.

And you have two main `for` loops, so each tweet (of which there are several GBs worth) is iterated through <s>twice</s> a staggering 4 times! Because you added in the `zip` function and then the iteration to write to the file. Any one of those points could be the cause of the memory error.

Unless absolutely necessary, try to only touch each piece of data once. As you iterate through a file, process the line and write it out immediately.

Try something like this instead:

```
out = open("output.csv", "ab")

filenames = ["8may.json", "9may.json", "10may.json", "11may.json", "12may.json"]

def process_tweet_into_line(line):
    # load as json, process turn into a csv and return
    return line

# change argument to the file you want to open
for name in file_names:
    with open(name) as file:
        for line in file:
            # only keep tweets and not the empty lines
            if line.rstrip():
                try:
                    tweet = process_tweet_into_line(line)
                    out.write(line)
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: thanks @Lego Stormtroopr but I'm having a little difficulty implementing your suggestion in my code.  Would you be able to help by fleshing it out a bit more please?  Thanks!